# Is there a method to extract integers from a string?

Tags: ruby, string

It seems that `String#to_i` only works when numbers are leading in a string.

**Works:**

`"123acb".to_i #=> 123`

**Doesn't work, but what I'm trying to accomplish:**

`"abc123def".to_i #=> 123`

I've been looking for a built in method to do this but I haven't found one. Is my only option to use a regular expression?

- EDIT - 
  Wow! Lots of good options! As an aside, was there any specific reason why `to_i` only deals with leading numbers?

Comment: How do you want to handle `"abc123def456ghi"`?  Two separate numbers or 123456?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What about doing something like this?

```
"abc123def".gsub(/\D/, '').to_i
# => 123
```

If you want to handle multiple numbers inside a big string, you can do

```
"a22bc123de4f004".split(/\D/).reject(&:empty?).map(&:to_i)
# => [22, 123, 4, 004]
```

Comment: You can use `\D` to match non-digt characters.

Comment: This works. I just find it odd that there is a method for number leading strings but not number trailing. Anyone know the reasoning for this?

Comment: Parsing a number from the _leading_ part of a string has a long history in programming, and likely came from the need to do lexical analysis - tokenizing inputs, that is.  You'll see it in JavaScript's `parseInt` among other places.

Answer (score 4):

Here's another approach, using `scan` rather than `split`:

```
>> "abc123def456ghi".scan(/\d+/).join.to_i
=> 123456
```

Note that `scan` keeps while `split` throws away....

To answer the actual question "is there a built-in method to do this?" you can see from the [Ruby String class documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/String.html) that there isn't, unless you take `scan`, `split`, `to_i`, `delete` and friends as "close enough" to being built-in.

Comment: Agreed.  `scan` and `[]` are nice alternatives, though, in case one prefers regexes that say what you want to keep instead of what you want to throw away.  `gsub` already appeared in an earlier (and rightly accepted) answer.

Comment: yes, you are right, `scan` is really useful in case we need the number parts seperately. nice to know all these options.

Answer (score 4):

```
"abc123def"[/\d+/].to_i
# => 123
```

Answer (score 3):

Another one using [delete](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/String.html#method-i-delete)

```
"abc123def456ghi".delete("^0-9").to_i
# => 123456
```

Answer (score 2):

How about the below using [***`String#tr`***](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/String.html#method-i-tr) ?

```
"abc123def456ghi".tr('a-z','').to_i
# => 123456
"abc123def456ghiA".tr('A-z','').to_i
# => 123456
```